# Numerical solution for coupled ODE with variable coefficients

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I'm trying to solve the system

```
Subscript[m, p] = 1.22*10^(19) * 1.52*10^(24);
Ag = Derivative[1][b][t]-1.5608310063810777811971842694*10^-43 b[t] Sqrt[(1 + 2.9079917009173806522983649735*10^-87 \[Psi][t]^2) (1.18253*10^149 f^4 (1 - (2.90799*10^-87 \[Psi][t]^2)/h^2)^2 + 1/2 Derivative[1][\[Psi]][t]^2)]

Bg = -((1.37552*10^63 f^4 \[Psi][t] (1 - (2.90799*10^-87 \[Psi][t]^2)/h^2))/h^2) - (3 \[Psi][t] Derivative[1][b][t]^2)/(4 b[t]^2 (1 + 2.9079917009173806522983649735*10^-87 \[Psi][t]^2)^2) + (3 Derivative[1][b][t] Derivative[1][\[Psi]][t])/ b[t] + Derivative[2][\[Psi]][t]
```

Using

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{Bg == 0, Ag == 0, \[Psi][0] == 2.1*(Subscript[m, p]),b[0] == 1, \[Psi]'[0] == 0}, {\[Psi], b}, {t, 0.0, 2.2*10^(-31)}, {f,h}, MaxSteps -> 100000, Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4,"Coefficients" -> FehlbergCoefficients,"StiffnessTest" -> False}];
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{\[Psi][f, h][t], b[f, h][t]} /. sol, {t, 0,6*10^(-32)}, AspectRatio -> 1], {f, 0.1, 10}, {h, 0.1, 10}]
```

Where the FehlbergCoefficients is:

```
Fehlbergamat = {{1/4}, {3/32, 9/32}, {1932/2197, -7200/2197, 
7296/2197}, {439/216, -8, 3680/513, -845/4104}, {-8/27, 
2, -3544/2565, 1859/4104, -11/40}};
Fehlbergbvec = {25/216, 0, 1408/2565, 2197/4104, -1/5, 0};
Fehlbergcvec = {1/4, 3/8, 12/13, 1, 1/2};
Fehlbergevec = {-1/360, 0, 128/4275, 2197/75240, -1/50, -2/55};
FehlbergCoefficients[4, p_] := 
N[{Fehlbergamat, Fehlbergbvec, Fehlbergcvec, Fehlbergevec}, p];
```

But it fails with $f=5$ and $h=1$, (I got "\$abort"). Using $f = 5$ and $h = 1$ before integration with jut "NDsolve" the result is what I'm looking for.

What I need is a plot $\psi \times t$ and $b \times t$  with variable coefficients h and f.

Comment: The quantity `Subscript[m, p]` is undefined.  In general, it is wise not to use superscript or subscript variables in computations.

Comment: Sorry: Subscript[m, p] = 1.22*10^(19) * 1.52*10^(24)

Comment: With v 11.2, I cannot reproduce the error you describe.  `InterpolatingFunction` does complain that some numerical values of `t` lie outside its range, but that is not serious and can be fixed.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, it is wierd, setting $f = 5$ and $h=1$ before integration the numerical values of $t$ lies inside its range. My version is 10.

Answer (score 2):

The computation as described in the question fails, because `FehlbergCoefficients`  is undefined.  It also seems unnecessary.  To produce the desired results, replace the second block of code by

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{Bg == 0, Ag == 0, ψ[0] == 2.1*(Subscript[m, p]), 
    b[0] == 1, ψ'[0] == 0}, {ψ, b}, {t, 0.0, 2.2*10^(-31)}, {f, h}];
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{ψ[f, h][t], b[f, h][t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 
    6*10^(-32)}, AspectRatio -> 1], {{f, 5}, 0.1, 10}, {{h, 1}, 0.1, 10}]
```

[image]

If it is necessary for some reason to employ `FehlbergCoefficients`, use the code provided under "A Method of Fehlberg" [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html#1681583708).

**Addendum**

Defining `FehlbergCoefficients`, as just added to the question, allows

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{Bg == 0, Ag == 0, ψ[0] == 2.1*(Subscript[m, p]), 
    b[0] == 1, ψ'[0] == 0}, {ψ, b}, {t, 0.0, 2.2*10^(-31)}, {f, h}, 
    Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
               "Coefficients" -> FehlbergCoefficients, "StiffnessTest" -> False}];
```

to be used instead.  It gives the same result.

Comment: My FehlbergCoefficients is defined... this plot is for $\psi$ or $b$ ?

Comment: @Kamog  Where in your question is `FehlbergCoefficients` defined?  The plot is of `b` as a function of `ψ`, as you specified by using `ParametricPlot`.  If, instead, you want `b` and `ψ` as functions of `t`, use `Plot` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put it in my question, but I did it now.... thank you

Comment: Using: Manipulate[ Plot[{\[Psi][f, h][t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 6*10^(-32)}, AspectRatio -> 1], {f, 0.1, 10}, {h, 0.1, 10}]

I got the same error... =\

Comment: I cannot reproduced the error.  I suggest that you copy the definitions from your question plus the code in my answer and run them in a new notebook.

Comment: I don't know what is happening, now I got the rights results, but sometimes it breaks, maybe it is a bug... Thanks alot.

Comment: For better use of Mathematica.SE,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.